# Apex trigger caused an unexpected exception:ANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,

Tags: update

Hi Members I have a after update trigger that calls a class method.

But the update fails with the error:

> Apex trigger caused an unexpected exception: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,

The trigger code that calls the class is:

```
trigger TotalAmountGlobalOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after undelete) {
   Opportunity[] Opptys = Trigger.new;
   //Call class method
   SumAmountChildOpportunity.CalculateTotalAmount(Opptys);
```

In the class method I do the following but it fails at the line: `Update gloOppty;`

```
//update Global Opportunity Stage
  Opportunity gloOppty = [select id, amount, StageName from opportunity where id =:GlobalOp];

  If (CountCloseWon==CountChildOpp) { 
      gloOppty.StageName = 'Closed Won'; 
      Update gloOppty;

      }
```

can any one suggest?

Comment: Hi Van, can you add any more information around the error message? it looks to have been cut short and therefore doesn't give the full detail to help find the cause and resolution

Comment: This is the full error message: Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger TotalAmountGlobalOpportunity caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: TotalAmountGlobalOpportunity: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0060Y00000H1XuHQAV; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 0060Y00000H1XuH) is currently in trigger TotalAmountGlobalOpportunity, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []:

Comment: Can you try run the process which caused the error again and capture debug logs? within the log, if you find the point at which the error message is thrown and backtrack through the log from that point this should help to understand what is causing this error and shed some more light on this.

Comment: the operation fails at "Update gloOppty" line code. There error is raised when I edit and save an opportunity record. I wonder if you can use Update xxNN in a after update trigger.

Comment: all code: public class SumAmountChildOpportunity {
    public static void CalculateTotalAmount(Opportunity[] opptys) {  
   
   id GlobalOp = 'xxxxx00000H1XuHQAV';
   Opportunity gloOppty = [select id, amount, StageName from opportunity where id =:GlobalOp];
   gloOppty.StageName = 'Closed Won'; 
   Update gloOppty; }}

Comment: Seems you have a `BeforeUpdate` trigger which tries to update the same `Opportunity` record which you are currently updating, or your `AfterUpdate` trigger is updating. Check if you have a `BeforeUpdate` trigger which updates `Opportunity` records.

Answer (score 2):

You have a classic trigger recursion issue. Your trigger is firing upon

```
after insert, after update, after undelete
```

and it performs an `update` DML operation. This guarantees that any time you insert, update, or undelete a record, your trigger will fire itself.

Object insert->after insert trigger->`update`->after update trigger->after update trigger

Object update->after update trigger->`update`->after update trigger

I have some concerns about the overall architecture here (it looks like you're implementing a synthetic roll-up summary, right?) but there's not enough code to make any recommendations. Potential fixes include using `before` events where applicable, where you don't have to fire DML, or using a static variable in your handler to inhibit recursion.

Comment: Thank you David, It works by using a static variable to inhibit recursion.